# Laravel - Guzzle calling POST returning GET

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I am trying to make a POST request in Guzzle, but the API I am calling is returning a response as if I made a GET request.

**Controller**

```php
class Controller extends BaseController
{
    const URL = 'http://apidomain.com';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    }

    public function createItem()
    {
        $body = [
            'itemId' => 123,
        ];

        $this->callPostRequest('api/items', $body);
    }

    private function callPostRequest($endpoint, $body)
    {
        $response = $this->client->post(self::URL.$endpoint, [
            'headers' => [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                'Authorization' => "Bearer {$this->getAccessToken()}",
            ],
            'form_params' => $body
        ]);

        dd(\GuzzleHttp\json_decode((string) $response->getBody()));
    }
}
```

**Provider**

```php
class ApiServiceProvider extends BaseServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/../Views', 'api');
        parent::boot();
    }

    public function routes()
    {
        $group = [
            'prefix' => '/api',
            'namespace' => 'Api\Controllers',
        ];

        Route::group($group, function () {
            Route::get('/create-item', 'Controller@createItem')
                ->name('api::create-item');
        });
    }
}
```

The post endpoint should allow me to add an item; however it is not adding and just returning a list of items currently persisted.

Comment: Could you post your routes please? along with the controller of which the functions you posted are part of.

Comment: Sorry, functions are in class Controller extends BaseController. And the route is in class ApiServiceProvider extends BaseServiceProvider

Comment: well yes, post the codes so that we can help :D :D we can't help if we can't see the codes.

Comment: Apologies, I have updated my post above